# Wamp Server suddenly does not execute php

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

Not sure what happened but my wamp server suddenly does not execute any php instead it comments all php out like this:

```
<!--?php
echo "hello world";

?-->
```

what the? (every file worked before so its not a coding issue)

Comment: So those characters are not in the source PHP file? You are 100% sure? Because my guess is the files got defaced by some mass editing process, like a search+replace in a HTML editor or somehting

Comment: nope they're being added in some how

Comment: the weirdest part is phpmyadmin still runs as well as the localhost page

Comment: What editor are you using to view/create these files?
http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got something similar when I try to insert php code on editors like TinyMCE, you might try to write the code in notepad and the upload your file via FTP, or if you want to write php code on a web-based application you could use ajaxplorer or extplorer.

To be 100% sure that is not a problem with the file you should dowload it via FTP an then open it with notepad.

Comment: I am using wamp server so I am just saving the files where they are directly located and using that address in the browser... I am also editing with notepad++

Comment: if you use an absolute path like "file:///C:/wamp/www/index.php" the script will never be processed, because you are accesing the file, you can also try with localhost and 127.0.0.1

Comment: good god.. and i thought i was losing my mind here lol.. wow just wow.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the php short-open tags (`<? ... ?>`) to the long-open php tags (`<?php ... ?>`).  Just do it for one file.  If it works, its a simple PHP setting (`short_open_tag`)

Comment: Its not commented out in the source though, just in the rendered text presented by the browser?

Comment: correct, I have tried multiple files that previously have worked.. even the simple hello world wont show up.. everything just somehow gets commented out